# How to retrieve the column from relation in YII2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am using ajax to call a method from the server that returns a string data. However I get the following error.

> PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get
>   property of non-object'

probably this line `$first_day=$row->tblStaff2->first_day_service;` gives the error.

```
   public function actionGet_loyalty() {
        $model = \common\models\staffs\TblStaff::find()->joinWith('tblStaff2')->all();
        $string = "<table class='table table-striped'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Number of Years</th></tr>";
        foreach ($model as $row) {
            $first_day=$row->tblStaff2->first_day_service;
            $midname = ucwords($row->midname);
            $name = ucwords($row->firstname) . " " . $midname[0] . ". " . ucwords($row->lastname);
            $string.="<tr>"
                    . "<td>" . $name . "</td>"
                    . "<td>" . $first_day . "</td>"
                    . "</tr>";
        }
        $string.="</table>";
        return $string;
    }
```

TblStaff relation

```
public function getTblStaff2() {
    return $this->hasOne(TblStaff2::className(), ['staff_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Find it below

```
public function actionGet_loyalty() {

    $model = \common\models\staffs\TblStaff::find()->all();
    $string = "<table class='table table-striped'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Number of Years</th></tr>";
    foreach ($model as $row) {

        //What I added
        foreach($row->tblStaff2 as $value){
            $first_day = $value->first_day_service;
        //Here is where it stopped

        $midname = ucwords($row->midname);
        $name = ucwords($row->firstname) . " " . $midname[0] . ". " . ucwords($row->lastname);
        $string.="<tr>"
                . "<td>" . $name . "</td>"
                . "<td>" . $first_day . "</td>"
                . "</tr>";
        }
    }
    $string.="</table>";
    return $string;
}
```

You can remove the comments i added to it when you get it working.

Comment: this still gives the same error. I think it is not necessary to have another foreach because it is a one to one relationship.